# Responsive Layout - PX, EM, or %?

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

I am building a responsive page layout and it works great so far, but I have a question:

Should I be using em, px or %?

For example, I want to have border radius applied to an element. Should I use this code:

```
border-radius: 1.563em;
```

Or this:

```
border-radius: 25px;
```

Should I be using ems for similar properties or should I stick with px?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Generally, don't use `px` for responsive layouts.

If you use a `px`-based media query, then [your layout may end up looking like crap when the user zooms](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/). And unfortunately, that I know all to well because I made that mistake too.

Regarding your example with `border-radius`, you may discover the two look really different when the `font-size` is increased - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3734579). The first and the third use `px` for border-radius, while the second and the fourth use `em`.

But there will be exceptions and if something doesn't feel right on zoom (for example, a `box-shadow` that looks exaggerated), try it with `px` as well.

Also check [this article](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/).

Comment: It would be better if this answer is updated as there are reference pixels now which can also be used for layouting

Answer (score 8):

Just for info, if it helps, it's possible to use `rem` . It solves the problem of "cascading size" with em. If you set

```
body { font-size :62.5 %; } /* Trick to have 1em =10px */

li {font-size:1.4em; }
```

your `<li>` will be 14px, but if you have a list in a list, the second level `<li>`  will be at 20px, and at third level will be 27px, etc..
With rem ( means "root em" ), all `<li>` are at the size you define.

More info : http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

and http://www.pompage.net/traduction/dimensionner-ses-fontes-avec-rem ( in french )

Comment: Just trolling, but I wanted to say that `rem`, although I've never used them, support fallback to `px`, `em`, `%`, etc. — so I might give them a whirl — but what about using an `em` fallback in a list? Still would require the long CSS markup... so might as well not use `rem` then?