# What's the preferred unit when doing responsive design?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a responsive website and I'm wondering what unit I should use? I've seen a lot of sites using pixels (px) for measurements and I've seen some using percent (%). Is there a preferred — or right — way of doing responsive design?

I've found percent to be hard to use, since it makes calculations hard and I've ended up with values like 2.754% and so on when setting widths/margins etc. Pixels seems easier, it's just simple addition and subtraction, but I've read that it isn't "future proof" or something like that and wont scale properly if the user zooms in the browser window. Is that still true?

If you have any experience or expertise, please share! I would love to hear what you guys have to say!

Thanks!

Comment: _Responsive_  and _absolute values_ (like pixels) contradict each other a little bit. Most often it's easier to use relative values for your plain properties (`width`) and absolute values for min/max (`max-width`, `min-width`). That way it still stays responsive, but you can make some assumptions on the width of the styled container.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450961/responsive-layout-px-em-or)

Comment: I think the answer are mostly right. Anyway, there're a lot of units in CSS. See this post from Chris Coyier: http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/

Answer (score 54):

For **layout** type things like the sizes of boxes, you want to use `%` because you will typically have several columns sized as a percentage of their parent that will stack on top of each other at a certain breakpoint (`width:100%`). No other unit will allow you to fill 100% of the space like `%` does.

For **padding/margins** use `em`, normally you will want to space your elements out relative to the size of your text. With `em` (the with of an 'M' character) you can quite easily say I want approximately 1 character spacing here.

For **borders** you can use `px` or `em`, there is a difference though. If you want your border to look like it's one pixel wide on all devices, use `1px`. It may not be one pixel on all devices however, high density displays convert `1px` into `2px` for example. If you want your border to be a size based on your font, use `em`.

For **fonts** use `em` (or `%`), the use of `em` carries through parents to children and it just a nicer unit to work with over `px`.

Comment: This is very far from a set of rules. This answer is a good guide but there are a lot of cases where using other units could work a lot better

Comment: For borders you may also use `thin`, `medium` and `thick`. They correspond to `1px`, `3px` and `5px` but are also scalable depending on your zoom, etc. They are also better than `em` because a border defined with `em` simply disappears when you zoom out and its width becomes less than `1px`.

Answer (score 12):

Of course you must use percentage. But with the `min-height`, `max-height`, `min-width`, `max-width` CSS keys.

**For the next generation**

**vw** and **vh**. The vw is 1/100th of the window's width and the vh is 1/100th of the window's height.
For responsiveness they are going to be the new units.

Comment: Yea I think they do work in a few browsers, no where near ready for non-experimental development though :P

Answer (score 6):

Use percentages along with min-width and max-width in pixels. This stops percentages making your divs too small or too large. eg

```
div {
    width:100%; //full width of browser
    max-width: 960px; //this means it will be 100% of the browser until 960px then it will stop expanding
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For layouts vh and vw are good because they are relative to the device's view port. They give you the possibility of designing with the view port of the device in mind. With this said you know what will show on the window and what won't without being too careful.

For text em is best because if it's responsive features.