# When do I use pixels/ems/rems and when percentages for responsive website (css)?

Tags: html, css

I went through other threads like this but I still don't quite get it. IMO I shouldn't use anything but percentages because everything needs to scale differently at different resolutions and that can only be done with percentages (right?).

EDIT: Here's the simple more specific question. I want to make my website responsive at the easiest way possible only using CSS and HTML. Is that better now?

Comment: If you want it to scale, and you don't want to use javascript, then yes, you need to use percentages

Comment: [This guide](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15850988/2065702) to using CSS units may be useful as might [Why do we use responsive units?](http://zachsaucier.com/blog/blog/2014/09/30/responsive-units/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of both, for example

```
main {
  width: XXrem; 
  max-width:100%;
}
```

So the element will have optimal font size-related width on larger screens but won't trigger horizontal scroll if the width calculated from `rem` is larger than viewport.

Another example:

```
main {
  width: 100%; 
  max-width:1024px;
}
```

Now you have a container that fills the viewport on smaller screens, but is fixed at 1024px on larger screens. Easier than setting breakpoints using media queries.

You should also look into [viewport based units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths): `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` - these are a bit like using percentages, but `1vw` is always 1% of the viewport width, not the parent container. And you can use these units for anything (like font size or border width), not just cointainers. You could even use `vw` to set the font-size, so units like `em` and `rem` would be related to the viewport.

Comment: Will check into that. Seems there's a lot to learn more :) Thanks

Comment: This hardly starts to cover each unit in CSS and the usage of them (the question is too broad)

Answer (score -1):

You can stick to any one or you can use both. Use percentage if you don't want to write more css in media queries. Elements size will become automatically  responsive if you use percentage. You can also use any of px, em or rem if you can handle in media queries.

Comment: So wait, just to get this straight...If I use only percentages I won't have to use media queries and the entire website will be responsive like that?

Comment: This answer is very misleading, suggesting that percentages are the only responsive unit

Comment: Are other ones vw, vh, vmin, vmax?