# How to insert html element at certain point using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

updated question link - [Page break at random places in browser print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477374/page-break-at-random-places-in-browser-print)

My requirement is such that I need to insert an HTML element with help of 'height from top and bottom' of that position.
I have tried to convey the exact requirement through the image attached.
As my HTML page with dynamic height can vary as per situation.

How can this be done using jQuery?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far except creating an image? Use some WYSIWYG tool instead of asking the forum.

Comment: did you tried to solve your problem ? If yes then share your code first..

Comment: And what does this even have to do with inserting the content dynamically using jQuery? If the content was static to begin with, the CSS you’d have to apply would be pretty much the same, no?

Comment: Why do you need to use JQuery? [Use HTML5 instead](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to position your elements at specific positions it doesn't matter where you put these elements in your markup. The positioning can be set using CSS. For example you could use:

```
.top {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
}

.middle {
   position: absolute;
   top: 150px;
}
```

Then add the classes to your divs.

Alternatively you can use responsive units like percent or view height (10vh for eg).

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question, position of element will be decided on run-time only.

Comment: [Use reponsive unit so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850988/whats-the-preferred-unit-when-doing-responsive-design)

Comment: Can't it be done without posistion:absolute? Browser print does not support it.

Comment: You could also use position: relative.. but then it depends on the rest of your content. So you have to know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in these function

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Ex:

```
<body>

    <script>
         $( function() {
             $("body").append("<div style='margin-top: 100px;'>Some div here</div><div style='margin-top:150px;'>div here</div><div style='margin-top:250px;margin-bottom:50px;'>some div here</div>");
         });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Link-only answers are not recommended. Provide an explication in case your links become obsolete.

Comment: Have you read the question? In this case I will not provide more answer than that. Is enough.

Comment: Thanks for asking I've read the question, as previously said "Take a look at this link" is not a "good" answer [Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers). You could instead explain the functions and how they can help him (with an example or something relevant)

Comment: Instead of answering me this... why just don't give him a proper answer? And stop commenting me my answer... If he needs examples... inside the links there are a lot of examples. What you want me to explain him... what is an html tag? How to use the css rule height or margin? I'm not a teacher. And he just ask about how to insert html elements by Jquery. That's the answer. What answer you provide?

Comment: [Here's mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51474379/8303093) JQuery isn't needed at all. Link-only answers are flagged and downvoted. **https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info** "Can you help me climb through this window?" "Why would you want to when there's an open door right there?" "oh."

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) instead, here's a working code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #div1 {
      margin: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
      background-color:lightblue;
    }
    
    #div2 {
      margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
      background-color:orange;
    }
    
    #div3 {
      margin: 100px 0px 50px 0px;
      background-color:red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Test Div1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Test Div2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <p>Test Div3</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### If you need responsive design

Try to use responsive units:

Use `em` it's a relative length (Relative length units specify a length relative to another length property. Relative length units scales better between different rendering mediums.)

2em means 2 times the size of the current font so he adapts himself to every screens/browser etc.

You may also use the % unit such as margin: 50% 25% 100% 30%;

Example above stated that:

### Top margin: 50% Right margin: 25% Bottom margin: 100% Left margin: 30%

Here's a link to the [`margin` documentation.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Link to others [CSS units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)