# What is the best way to set width and height of elements?

Tags: html, css, web

Every website has elements and their width and height must be set. here is my question how do we can set the width and height such that the website works correctly on different monitors with different width/height? is `px` preferred to `%`? when we should px and when we should use %? what are advantages and disadvantages of each one?

Comment: It depends. Have a read of http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/ and http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids to get you started.

Comment: Width and height don't have to be specifically set on elements on a website. Of course they can be but they don't have to be. If you are settings widths it will depend whether your website is fixed width or responsive/adaptive.

Comment: They serve for different purposes. Having elastic or static dimensions have both advantages/disadvantages but, more important, respond to specific design decisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends upon the type of your website and how you want to response to various screen resolutions.

Just using `% and px` is not enough, there are other unit for text size for example `em and pt` etc.

Also we have `media queries`

http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/common-techniques-in-responsive-web-design.html#fbid=YIeEpYZXBt-

Relevant SO Question [Responsive Layout - PX, EM, or %?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450961/responsive-layout-px-em-or)

Answer (score 4):

Use px when you want to specify a fixed/static height in pixels. % refers to the percentage total of the elements parent. Using percent means the web site will adapt when the browser is resized wheras using pixels it will not.

Which one you choose really depends on the look and feel that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: when I use `px` and resize the browser, scroll-bar appears but when I use `%` and resize the browser all the website will be out of order. what shall I do ?

Comment: Do you mean the scroll bar on the browser? This is because using pixels it cannot resize as you adjust the browser window so it adds the scrollbar to allow you to see all the content. If you were using percentages then it would try to adapt the content to fit on the browser window and therefore would not require the scrollbars. You can however use the overflow css attribute to add scrollbars to any element.

Answer (score 1):

it all depends of what kind of web you plannning to do.

Many web pages use a container with a fixed width on pixels (like 960px). then it's extremely easy if you have a well-made predesign on photoshop, illustrator, indesign, etc to work with pixels. These webs though doesn't work well outside PC screens as if you have a window width smaller than the container the content won't be show unless scrolling horizontally.

Now, if you want your content to adjust to any horizontal width you should use % but imo it is much difficult and you need a clear idea what you want to show on each possible width before starting working.

If you decide to go for a "responsive" design... the work will be harder. I recomend you to use something like:

```
@media screen and  (min-width:600px) {}
@media screen and  (min-width:800px) {}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {}
@media screen and (min-width:1524px) {}
```

in your CSS to tweek your classes wahtever necesary for each width (or platform). (there's also many other usefull @medias