# QBO3 override css for standard inputs

Tags: css

What is the css to change the an input field with class qbo-xxxx? I would like to change the qbo-date field to width of 200px. Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.section {
    background:none;
    color:#777;
    border-bottom: #CCC 1px solid;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

form.grid label:not(.radio) {
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with XSLT.  The fact that the CSS rules appear inside an XSLT template is irrelevant -- the same question could have been posed (and ought to have been  posed) without the XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; You should use something like:

```
.qbo-date
{
    width: 16em !important;
}
```

---

QBO3 offers several standard classes for common input types, defined in qbo.ApplicationWeb / Styles / qbo3.less, including:

- .qbo-date
- .qbo-money
- .qbo-zip
- .qbo-int
- .qbo-numeric
- .qbo-percent

The .qbo-date class is defined as:

```
.qbo-date
{
    width: 8em !important;
}
```

Note the [use of em vs px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450961/responsive-layout-px-em-or) - your override should consider responsive design too!

Given that qbo-date uses 8em by default, if you want to double the input length, use 16em (as noted at the top).

Consider experimenting directly in Chrome; you can edit CSS directly in the debugger:

[image: qbo-date with 8em]

vs:

[image]